# Como instalar a biblioteca Pandas no Python 3

Tags: pandas

Gostaria de saber como faço a instalação da biblioteca Pandas no Manjaro, na versão Python 3.4.3 -

Comment: Poderia disponibilizar mais informações? Qual o sistema operacional?

Comment: Uso o sistema operacional Linux - Manjaro. E a versão que utilizo do Python é 3.4.3

Answer (score 3):

Utilizei o comando:

```
sudo pacman -S  python-pandas
```

E deu certo :)

Answer (score 0):

Em geral, o comando `pip3 install pandas` deve funcionar caso você tenha o `pip3` instalado. Pra conferir você pode também usar o comando `which pip3` que deve retornar o local onde ele está instalado.

Se você usa o gerenciador de pacotes Anaconda, pode também instalar o Pandas com o comando `conda install pandas`.

Answer (score 0):

Sempre que for usar `pip3 install pandas` deve-se dar permissão, isso é, sempre use como: `sudo pip3 install pandas`

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Se você já tem o python e o pip instalados, faça o seguinte:

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

Outra forma é usando o comando do pip diretamente:

```
pip install pandas
```

As duas formas devem funcionar similarmente, dado que o link simbólico do python e do pip apontem para a versão do python 3 que você mencionou que usa. Isso pode ser verificado com o comando:

```
python --version
```

Caso não seja a versão 3.x, verificar então o comando python3. Usando o pip pode ser feito então assim:

```
python3 -m pip install pandas
```

ou

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.